# how to align this footer to bottom inside nav menu with responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried this code to align this footer at the bottom of the nav-bar .how can get this at bottom, it should be responsive

```
<div class="sidebar" data-color="green">
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">
                /*menu code*/
            </ul>
            <footer class="footer pull-bottom"> 
                /*code*/
            </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(img.png)"></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: your trying to add it to sidebar? not to footer?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: yes to sidebar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should put footer at the bottom.

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```